# What is data as a "string without null bytes, not Binary"?

Tags: python, pdf, typeerror, poppler

I can use the [poppler library](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) to easily create an image from a pdf using:

```
pdftoppm -png myfile.pdf > myfile.png
```

I'm now trying to use the [python-poppler library](https://launchpad.net/poppler-python) to do the same from within Python. After installing the lib (`sudo apt-get install python-poppler`) I can load in a pdf file using the following:

```
doc = poppler.document_new_from_file('file://'+urllib(inputF), password=None)
```

but I now want to load a pdf file from binary. I thought I could use the method `poppler.document_new_from_data()`, so I tried the following, which returns a type error:

```
>>> d = poppler.document_new_from_data(userDoc.binary)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: document_new_from_data() argument 1 must be string without null bytes, not Binary
```

I'm unsure what this means though. What "data" can be a "*string without null bytes, not Binary*"? I tried checking out the source of the method, but the source files ([here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~poppler-python/poppler-python/trunk/files)) don't even contain a single `.py` file.

I tried converting the binary to base64, but that leads to an error saying `TypeError: Required argument 'length' (pos 2) not found`.

Any help would be welcome!

[EDIT] 
Thanks to the tip of @Vaulstein I now got a bit further:

```
s = binascii.a2b_base64(userDoc.binary)
r = poppler.document_new_from_data(s, len(s), password='')Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error (3): Illegal character <75> in hex string
Syntax Error (4): Illegal character <df> in hex string
Syntax Error (5): Illegal character <5d> in hex string
Syntax Error (6): Illegal character <28> in hex string
Syntax Error (7): Illegal character <6e> in hex string
Syntax Error (8): Illegal character <3f> in hex string
Syntax Error (9): Illegal character <ca> in hex string
Syntax Error (10): Illegal character <89> in hex string
Syntax Error (11): Illegal character <db> in hex string
>>> r = poppler.document_new_from_data(s, len(s), password='')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
GError: PDF document is damaged
```

But it still doesn't seem to be the correct encoding. Any other idea how I can do this?

Comment: Have you tried `binascii.a2b_base64(data)` ?

Comment: @Vaulstein - I just tried that, and that indeed brings me a bit further. I now get a `GError: PDF document is damaged`. I added a new part to the question. Any idea what could be wrong now?

Comment: You should check the link [poppler](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=668777).

Comment: @Vaulstein - Thank you for that link. So I now understand that the problem is that "the very first object in such PDF is a stream starting with "<" 
character", and the solution should be "adding a dummy object to the PDF fixes the problem". Would you know how I can "add a dummy object to the PDF"? Any tips on that would be very welcome!

Comment: you can find the difference on the link between two documents [test1.tex](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?msg=3;filename=test1.tex;att=2;bug=668777) and [test2.tex](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?msg=3;filename=test2.tex;att=3;bug=668777)
this is how the dummy object was added: `\immediate\pdfobj stream {}`

Answer (score 2):

The [poppler_document_new_from_data](https://developer.gnome.org/poppler/unstable/PopplerDocument.html#poppler-document-new-from-data) call requires to pass the whole binary data, including 0 bytes, as the first argument, as a `char*` (which typically is a `str` in Python 2). You discovered a bug in poppler-python. As @Vaulstein pointed out in a comment, it has been [reported upstream but is unresolved](https://bugs.launchpad.net/poppler-python/+bug/312462).

As a workaround, either store the PDF to a file and use the ..new_from_file call, or use the `gi.repository.Poppler`module instead. (The module comes with PyGObject; see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682297/displaying-pdf-files-with-python3) for an example, and [here's the documentation for poppler_document_new_from_data](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Poppler-0.18/classes/Document.html#Poppler.Document.new_from_data).)

Comment: @Philip: I think that the bug has already been reported but not resolved.
It is present in the list of bugs.